# SQL dateofyear , How to convert to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for your suggestions --- I have the following;

```
DATEPART(dayofyear,SalesDateTime) Day
```

and I am grouping by // with the following

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(dayofyear,SalesDateTime)
```

the result is

```
    Count | Day
------------------------
        1   92
        2   93
        2   94
        2   121
        3   123
```

How do I convert `dayofyear` to dd/mm/yyyy or normal time/date format?

Comment: `CAST(SalesDateTime as DATE)` as you already have a datetime column.

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala apparently DATE() is not recognized in SQL Server, I guess it would do in mysql

Comment: yeah..you can use `cast`

Comment: Oh Yes! Sweet! @Vamsi Prabhala it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can add the number of days to the beginning of the year you want:

```
select dateadd(day, DayOfYear - 1, '2018-01-01')
```

It would seem you want something like:

```
select dateadd(day, datepart(DayOfYear, SalesDateTime) - 1, '2018-01-01')
```

But this seems a bit silly.  Why not just use `SalesDateTime`?  Or remove the time component using `cast(SalesDateTime as date)`?

Comment: @zufuzoje . . . That is the name of your column.

Answer (score 0):

Convert DateTime to Date and group by date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SalesDateTime) Day
..
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, SalesDateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `cast` as `date`;

```
select cast(SalesDateTime as date) from table 
group by cast(SalesDateTime as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

To choose the date format you need to CONVERT. Check this website http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx  so in your case it would look like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,dayofyear,103)
```